# MATLAB for loop to multiple columns

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I have the following block of code that I developed in MATLAB to calculate RSI.

```
%RSI Calculation
n = [14:2:18];

for i = 1:n
    gainC = diff(ABC).*((diff(ABC))> 0);
    lossC = -(diff(ABC)).*((diff(ABC)) < 0);
    avg_gainC = movmean(gainC,[i-1 0],'omitnan'); 
    avg_lossC = movmean(lossC,[i-1 0],'omitnan'); 
    RS = (avg_gainC ./ avg_lossC);
    ABC_RSI = 100 - (100 ./ (1+RS));
end
```

I need to know how the output of the loop creates the table 'ABC_RSI' and the columns relate to the `n`. The expected output is a `14w_RSI` `16w_RSI` and `18w_RSI`.

I have tried to use:
`ABC_RSI.n = 100 - (100 ./ (1+RS));`

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but if I assume that `ABC` is a column/row vector and you're trying to store the `RSI` for each different values of `n`. If this is the case, then I suggest you do a double for-loop of the form

```
%RSI Calculation
n = [14:2:18];

for j = 1 : length( n)
    n_j = n( j);
    for i = 1 : n_j
        gainC = diff(ABC).*((diff(ABC))> 0);
        lossC = -(diff(ABC)).*((diff(ABC)) < 0);
        avg_gainC = movmean(gainC,[i-1 0],'omitnan'); 
        avg_lossC = movmean(lossC,[i-1 0],'omitnan'); 
        RS = (avg_gainC ./ avg_lossC);
        ABC_RSI( :, j) = 100 - (100 ./ (1+RS));
    end
end
```

The output `ABC_RSI` will then have the same number of columns as `ABC` and same number of rows as the *length* of `n`.

Comment: Thanks, it's close, however it seems to replicate the first number in 'n' 3 x times, rather than run the calculation on each of the numbers. So the result is three identical columns.

Comment: There was a mistake a typo in the code I provided. I was using `n` in the second loop rather than `n_j`. But even then, if `ABC` is a column vector/matrix, then the result is going to be the same since `movmean` is simply returning the column vector/matrix. Could you please provide an example of `ABC`?